# jQuery get "distinct" elements from a document

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a footnotes helper for ASP.NET MVC.
I have generated on my page a set of links similar to:

`<a rel="footnote" href="#fn:footnote1" data-text="note" data-ref="1">1</a>`

I want to generate the bottom section containing the actual notes. The goal is to take the `href` and `data-text` from each link and create a `li` element at the bottom of the page.

This is the HTML generated for this section:

```
<div id="6c708d57-abc0-4e53-ab0c-913f0b8c8020" class="footnote">
    <hr />
    <ol></ol>
</div>
```

And the corresponding script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var footnotes = $('#6c708d57-abc0-4e53-ab0c-913f0b8c8020 ol');

    $('a[rel="footnote"]').each(function () {
        var reference = $(this).text();
        var text = $(this).attr('data-text');
        var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);
        footnotes.append('<li id="' + href + '">' + text + '</li>');
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is when I want to reuse the same note on several elements, the note gets duplicated in the bottom section. I'd like it to appear only once.

What is the simplest solution to retrieve a semantically distinct list of `A`?

I have looked at `jQuery.unique()` but my elements are already unique as far as the DOM is concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store notes in a hash as you go - if one already exists, go on by `return`ing in iteration step:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var footnotes = $('#6c708d57-abc0-4e53-ab0c-913f0b8c8020 ol');

    var notesProcessed = {};

    $('a[rel="footnote"]').each(function () {

        var reference = $(this).text();
        var text = $(this).attr('data-text');
        var href = $(this).attr('href').substring(1);

        if(notesProcessed[href])
          return;        

        footnotes.append('<li id="' + href + '">' + text + '</li>');

        notesProcessed[href] = true;

    });
});
</script>
```